# VBA SQL Sum Operation in Form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

In my `form` i want to use a `sum` on row `SWS` from `tblKurse` used in the `query` for the `form`. On a Button Click event i want to `sum` the values in that row whenever the criterion in my `where` is met. Problem is i get an `invalid argument` error whenever i run it. I just cant find my mistake. Maybe someone can help.

Heres the function that i call after the button click event:

```
Public Function chkSWS() As Integer

    Dim db As Database
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String

    Set db = CurrentDb

    strSQL = "SELECT SUM(tblKurse.SWS) As Stunden " _
    & "FROM tblKurse " _
    & "WHERE tblKurse.Dozent_ID = " & Me.cmbKursDOzent

    Debug.Print strSQL
    Debug.Print Me.Dozent_ID
    Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbForwardOnly)

    chkSWS = rst![Stunden]

    Set rst = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing

End Function
```

Error points on the "Set rst" line, so it might been a bad `Select` statement?

printed SQL Statement:

```
SELECT SUM(tblKurse.SWS) As Stunden FROM tblKurse WHERE tblKurse.Dozent_ID = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbForwardOnly)
```

to this

```
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenSnapshot)
```